# Cover points with specified amount of cuboids and minimize overlap

Tags: geometry

Given a list of Points (the coords are pure integeres), I want to cover all of them with cuboids.

The Problem is, I have a limited number of cuboids I can use. Of course I would like to have a minimal overlap.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Currently I have no idea where to look.

**Example:**

Given:

```
Arbitrary number of Points: {(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,2,1),(1,2,4),(1,1,3),(1,3,2),(1,3,3)}

Maximum number of cuboids: 2
```

Output: `2 cuboids which are minimizing the number of included Points which are not given.`

**Or to express it in a more formal way:**

forall p in given Points exists at least one cuboid which covers the point.
AND the number of Points, which are included in the cuboid and are not in the given Points has to be <= than for all other given cuboids.

Notice, that you can count the number of Points, because the coordinates are element of the natural numbers.

Comment: What is the "limited number" you speak of? Also, what do you mean by "cover the points"?

Comment: I added an example to the question, did I answered your question?

Comment: No, you did not. What do you mean by "Points which are not given"? I also don't see how cuboids come into play here.

Comment: What's the length of the cuboids?

Comment: the number of allowed cuboids is a parameter to the problem